# Changing permissions discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Ok so I've been working on a bot that creates channel overrides using discord.js. I'm kind of new to discord.js but I checked the documentary and it seems that the correct method to use when changing overrides is what I used in the code below, but I get an error message and I have absolutely no clue as to how I can fix it.

```js
if (command == 'lockdown') {
 if (commandArgs == '') {
  let channel = msg.channel;
  let roles = msg.guild.roles;
  console.log(roles);
  let testRole = 708384707015868486;
  channel
   .overwritePermissions(testRole, { SEND_MESSAGES: false }, 'closing up shop')
   .then(console.log)
   .catch(console.log);
 }
}
```

This is the code for that specific command, but I get the following error message.

```
TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied overwrites is not an Array or Collection of Permission Overwrites.
    at TextChannel.overwritePermissions (/home/runner/Ecliptical-Productions-V3/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/GuildChannel.js:208:9)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Ecliptical-Productions-V3/index.js:25:17)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/Ecliptical-Productions-V3/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/Ecliptical-Productions-V3/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/Ecliptical-Productions-V3/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/Ecliptical-Productions-V3/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/Ecliptical-Productions-V3/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/Ecliptical-Productions-V3/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16) {
      [Symbol(code)]: 'INVALID_TYPE'
    }
```

How can I fix this error? I checked the channel overrides after the command and the changes weren't made, I've been trying to fix this for ages but I can't find the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`overwritePermissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions) method wants an Array or a Collection of [`OverwriteResolvables`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/OverwriteResolvable) as the first argument. Instead, your first argument is the id of the role you want to change the permissions for.

Change the `channel.overwritePermissions` to the example code below and give it a try.

```js
channel.overwritePermissions(
 [
  {
   id: testRole,
   deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
  },
 ],
 'Closing up shop'
);
```

In this example, the supplied OverwriteResolvable is of type [`OverwriteData`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/OverwriteData) which can be defined with a simple Object structure.

Answer (score 0):

`overwritePermissions` expects an array and you supplied it with 2 objects.

```js
channel.overwritePermissions(
 [  //<--- you are missing these
  {
   id: message.author.id,
   deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
  },
 ], //<--- you are missing these
 'Needed to change permissions'
);
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions

Answer (score 0):

If you have "message" defined you can use "message.channel" to get the channel you typed the message in.

`message.channel.createOverwrite(message.guild.id, { SEND_MESSAGES: false })`

You can see that above that would change send messages permissions for all roles except moderation roles and if you wanted to send a message after you can use the ".then()" function, If you use V12 everything i told you will work fine, I suggest you research before asking there's loads of information and tutorials online you can find.